# knitr::opts_chunk$set failing to change figure size in R Markdown

Tags: r, knitr

I'm not sure why my global options are not working. I have restarted R, and upgraded to latest version of knitr. I set my global options as in the chunk below, and `knitr::opts_chunk$get()` indicates that the default fig.width & fig.height are the values I've set them to, but the chunk output is not reflecting these height and width values (i.e., my image should now be taller than it is wide).

````
```{r global_options}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.width=5, fig.height=7) 
```

```{r}
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + 
    geom_point()
```
````

[image]

Comment: This works fine when I knit it. I can change the values to something like 5 and 12 and get a long and narrow plot. Do you have any yaml settings at the top of the file?

Comment: @FelipeFlores, just the standard: ---
title: ""
author: ""
date: ""
output: html_document ---

Comment: Very strange. I literally copy-pasted this and worked like a charm. Would restarting your session do anything?

Comment: I had a similar issue and I still can't tell if global options get arbitrarily dropped in some knits or it has something to do with caching but, in my code, repeating the equivalent of `knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.width=5, fig.height=7)` in a later chunk but before my first plots seemed to solve the problem (though it still doesn't explain what's going wrong).